# Error when running yeoman init

Tags: command, yeoman

I'm getting the following error when I run `yeoman init angularù, although the angular part shouldn't matter, since I got the same error:

```
create        test/lib/angular-mocks.js
<WARN> Unable to create directory "/Users/myuserfolder/test/lib" (Error code: ENOTDIR). Use --force to continue. </WARN>
```

it seems to be trying to create a file in my home folder, which is weird, becuse I cd'd into a folder designated for my project. What could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a known [bug](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/635) caused by you having a Gruntfile in your home directory.